# powershell - create subdir struct adding a zero on single digit months

Tags: powershell

i'm super new to powershell.

attempting to create a basic directory structure yyyy/mm

what it creates:

```
C:\2020
├───1
├───10
├───11
├───12
├───2
├───3
├───4
├───5
├───6
├───7
├───8
└───9
```

i'm trying to add a zero to months jan = 01...september 09. oct = 10, nov = 11, dec = 12

desired result:

```
C:\2020
├───01
├───02
├───03
├───04
├───05
├───06
├───07
├───08
├───09
├───10
├───11
└───12
```

this is the nested loop i have. any inputs are appreciated. thank you in advance

```
      for ($i=2020; $i -le 2022;$i++) #years from 2020 to 2022
            { 
                for ($j=01; $j -le 12;$j++) # for months eg 01-12
                    {
                        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path\$i\$j -Force
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1) to add a preceding zero here.

```bsh
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$path\$i\$(([string]$j).PadLeft(2, '0'))" -Force
```

2 = How many characters in total the string should be.
'0' = The character you want to use preceding the given value.

Also, your variable needs to be a string for PadLeft so I've cast it to that type - `([string]$j).PadLeft()`

For example

```bsh
PS >  "2".PadLeft(2, '0')
02
PS >  "2".PadLeft(3, '0')
002
PS >  "2".PadLeft(4, '0')
0002
PS >  "2".PadRight(4, '0')
2000
PS >  "2".PadLeft(5, 'a') 
aaaa2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the format operator to add leading zeros. See https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html

```
2020..2022 | % {
    $year = $_
    1..12 | % {
        $month = "{0:d2}" -f $_
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$path\$year\$month" -Force
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way with a datetime object in the for loop.  "| % tostring 00" pads 0's with integer input.

```
for ($date = [datetime]'1/2020'; $date -le '12/2022'; $date = $date.addMonths(1)) {
  mkdir "$($date.year)\$($date.month | % tostring 00)" -whatif
}


What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\01".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\02".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\03".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\04".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\05".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\06".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\07".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\08".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\09".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\10".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\11".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2020\12".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\01".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\02".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\03".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\04".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\05".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\06".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\07".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\08".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\09".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\10".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\11".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2021\12".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\01".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\02".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\03".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\04".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\05".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\06".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\07".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\08".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\09".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\10".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\11".
What if: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\Users\js\2022\12".
```

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
for ($i=2020; $i -le 2022;$i++) { 
    for ($j=01; $j -le 12;$j++) {
        if ($j -le 9) {
            [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$path\$i\0$j")
        } else {
            [system.io.directory]::CreateDirectory("$path\$i\$j")
        }
    }
}
```

I added an if statement with a '0'

You'd do less computation on the entire list of objects, so it is a bit faster, and not too dissimilar to your original attempt.

Comment: It works, which is the important thing. The most likely reason for a downvote is that it specifically only works for two digits (unless you make a more complicated elseif or sub-calculation with powers of ten), rather than using more generic string formatting. I'd personally consider this premature optimization, as performance is unlikely to be an issue when generating such a small list, and for larger lists you'd need to refactor anyway. Not an issue for months of year, and it works, so I'd have no complaints about seeing this in prod.

Comment: I personally have to disagree with this answer. Adding a branch to this code just to save a few ms is completely unnecessary in the context of the problem. Powershell is a language you use because it's easy and you can quickly write scripts, not because it performs well (there's some saying here about devs go fast). _Just one example: `ForEach-Object` is 5-10x slower than `.{process{}}`, but people still use `ForEach-Object`._ The additional complexity and ergo work required on behalf of humans is not worth it in 99% of cases.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I find `foreach`|`for` faster and more readable than `%`, and I feel writing things in a more readable way lends itself to better serviceability, should this script find itself running somewhere on a task scheduler in the future and someone unfamiliar with powershell needs to service it. That may just be due to the environment I work in.

I definitely agree that write time beats read time though, and you make valid points.